# Record change in variable each day

Tags: ios, swift

I have a variable that changes its value on a daily basis. How do I record that value for each day with respective date and display it in a UItableview.

Comment: How many days do you want to keep?

Comment: @PhillipMills I want to record everyday. I have a bead roller in my app. Basically the user rolls beads every day to chant gods name. At the end of the day I want the app to automatically save whatever bead value is and put it in a tableview. So I don’t know how to retrieve and save the variable value per day.

Comment: You could use Coredata even if it feels a bit like overkill for this, another option is simple text file you append to each day. I think you need to do some more research on your own

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks

Comment: The simple text file sounds good if that's all you're doing.  Maybe look at CloudKit if you want to share between devices.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest) to save your `Model` each day.

This [link](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#models) will help you to define your model.

And this [link](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#working-with-realm-objects) will explain to you how to save and retrieve your model from the database.